# Вывести в shell строки, не содержащие

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

Хочу вывести содержимое документа без комментариев. Комментарии традиционно начинаются с "#".
Знаю, как вывести только комментарии, например, через sed: **sed -n '/#/p' filename**, a вот совершить обратное действие проблема. Возможно, есть вариант решения через awk

Comment: `sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' filename > result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Знаю, как вывести только комментарии, например, через sed: `sed -n '/#/p' filename`, a вот совершить обратное действие…

просто инвертируйте условие:

```
$ sed -n '/#/!p' файл
```

цитата из [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses-overview.html):

> Appending the '!' character to the end of an address specification
>   (before the command letter) negates the sense of the match.

`/#/` — это спецификация адреса (адресует все строки, содержащие символ `#`). добавляете после неё `!` — условие инвертируется.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
# Remove comment-only lines.
/^[[:space:]]*#.*$/d

# Remove comments.
s/[[:space:]]*#.*$//
```

Пример до:

```
non-comment 1 and don't remove the line below

# comment
  # comment with space
non-comment 2 # and a comment
```

Пример после:

```
non-comment 1 and don't remove the line below

non-comment 2
```